# How to check existence of a table when create table using GUI

Tags: user-interface, sql-server-2012

I want to creat a table using GUI in SQL Server 2012, but I can't find anywhere to check existence of a table.

I found solution for my question:

- select database click right mouse -> select Task -> Generate Script -> Set Scripting Options-> Advanced-> Change value of "Check for object existence" is True.

Answer (score 0):

In SSRS, expand out the Server; expand out the "Databases" node; expand out your database; expand out "Tables".

Your table will be listed if it's present.

Comment: sorry, maybe my question isn't clear. I mean when create table using T-SQL, we can use command IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[YourTable]') to check existance of table. And my question is how to do that using GUI?